# Publish NuGet package without source code

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a .NET project targeting .NET Standard 2.0. When compiled, this project yields an assembly in the `./bin/Debug/netstandard2.0` directory. I want to package this assembly into a NuGet package. However, I do *not* want to include the source code. In an attempt to do this, I currently am running the following from the command line:

```
dotnet build MyProject.csproj
dotnet pack --configuration Debug MyProject.csproj
dotnet nuget push bin/Debug/MyProject.1.0.0.nupkg --source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/my-organization --api-key [personal-access-token] --skip-duplicate --no-symbols true
```

The commands listed above successfully publish a NuGet package to my package registry. I can also successfully install this package via Visual Studio. However, when I attempt to compile the code, I get an error that says the namespace in the package cannot be found. I can see the package listed under the "dependencies/packages" node in Visual Studio. However, I cannot (or don't know how to) explore which namespaces are actually in it. But, when I right-click on it, and choose "Open Folder in File Explorer", I see the source code. I also see a *.nupkg file, a *.nupkg.sha512 file, and a .nupkg.metadata file.

My question is, how do I publish my NuGet package such that the source code is *not* included?

Answer (score 1):

The `dotnet pack` would pack the code into a NuGet package. We recommend you use [nuget.exe tool](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) with [.nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#example-nuspec-files), it could only pack your generated files.