# How can I create a Nuget Package whose source code is not visible?

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I wrote a netstandard2.0 class library. I want to publish this as a Nuget package. I right-clicked on the project and made the necessary adjustments in the Package field. Likewise, when I right click and select Pack, it creates a nuget package. No problems so far.

When using the Nuget package I shared in another project, the entire source code of the library is visible. How can I prevent this? I want the user to see only the function names in the class. He should not be able to see the contents of the functions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Publish NuGet package without source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68303201/publish-nuget-package-without-source-code)

Comment: I saw this but couldn't figure out how to create the nuspec.file content. I made a few attempts but failed.

Comment: It's just a plain XML file - there's a link to some samples from the answer on the linked question.